# registerActivityForResult getting the result from the camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

especially @Muntashir Akon, I'm from "Down Under", please if you could spare some time.

As we all know now `startActivityForResult` is **DEPRECATED**, thanks google.
How do we get the result from a camera .. here is my code `intentData` always returns **null**. Please help this is driving me crazy.

I am possibly using the wrong caller, but I can't seem to find anything on the internet

for @Muntashir Akon, the actual caller is yours ...

```
    protected final RegisterActivityResultHelper<Intent, 
         ActivityResult> activityLauncher =
            RegisterActivityResultHelper.registerActivityForResult( 
                     this );
```

```
RegisterActivityForResult
    ActivityResultLauncher activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult( Object result )
        {
        }
    });
```

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void takePhoto()
    {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File outputDir = getCacheDir();
        File file;
        try
        {
            file = File.createTempFile( uuid, ".jpg", outputDir );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        Uri uri;
        try
        {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( Objects.requireNonNull(
                    getApplicationContext()),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", file );
        }
        catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
        {
            return;
        }

        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri );
        activityLauncher.launch( intent );
        activityLauncher.setOnActivityResult( result ->
        {
            if( result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CANCELED )
                return;

            Intent intentData = result.getData();
            if( intentData == null )
            {
                return;
            }

            Uri imageUri = intentData.getData();
            Bundle bundle = intentData.getExtras();

            Log.e("URI",imageUri.toString());
            Bitmap bmp = ( Bitmap ) bundle.get( "data" );
        } );
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [`TakePicture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture) contract?

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, we had the same idea at the same time lol, see below, although I did try this before and it did not work, so obviously I was doing the wrong thing, but all good now

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have the answer and I hope it helps everyone else

Launcher ...

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> takeAPhoto = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), result ->
    {
        if( !result  )
            return;

        Helpers.loadPicIntoGlide( ivItemImage, photoTakenUri );
        etImageName.setText( photoTakenUri.getPath() );
    } );
```

Caller ...

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void takePhoto()
    {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File outputDir = getCacheDir();
        File file;
        try
        {
            file = File.createTempFile( uuid, ".jpg", outputDir );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            photoTakenUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( Objects.requireNonNull(
                    getApplicationContext()),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileProvider", file );
        }
        catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
        {
            return;
        }

        takeAPhoto.launch( photoTakenUri );
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://medium.com/realm/startactivityforresult-is-deprecated-82888d149f5d) post about `RegisterActivityForResult` on Medium, it has some examples for using it including the camera.